# What is the best way to map/align my reads on a given genome?

Tags: rna-seq, sequence-alignment, rna-alignment, bowtie2

I am frequently using a ballgown package for my rnaseq analysis, but recently I have had a new task to have my reads mapped on two different genomes to understand the level of alignment between the two, therefore I wonder what is the best tool to do this? I have single-end reads.
What I need is to have a percentage of uniquely mapped fragments, mapped to multiple loci and, say, unmapped. Can `bowtie` do the job? Is there a standard explanation procedure explained elsewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward analysis, assuming that you want to measure something like "how many reads align to genome 1, and how many reads align to genome 2?".

- The [bowtie2 manual has a section](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/manual.shtml#getting-started-with-bowtie-2-lambda-phage-example) on this.
- There are [other tutorials for bowtie2](https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/bioiteam/Mapping+with+bowtie2+Tutorial).
- [bwa](http://bio-bwa.sourceforge.net/) is also [well-suited to this task](http://evomics.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/genomics_tutorial_2019.pdf).

You should be able to then use [samtools](http://www.htslib.org/) to compute [statistics](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-stats.html) on your alignments.